# How to loop through this csv file with multiple values in one column

Tags: sharepoint-online, csv, loop

I'm trying to get the following code (originally taken from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-online-57f24eca) to read through a CSV file where one of the columns has two user groups. I've tried using -split to break down the contents but I'm not having any luck and keep getting "Group cannot be found" Is anyone able to help me please?

CSV example:

```
Folder,Group,Role
RenameMe,"Group1,Group2",Edit
RenameMe/TestFolder1,Group1,Edit
```

Code:

```
#Get the user credentials
$username = "username"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

#Input Parameters
$url = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/site1"
$csvfilepath ='C:\temp\data.csv'
$libname ='Shared Documents/Folder1'

#References
Add-Type -Path 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'


#CreateFolder with Permissions Function
function CreateFolderWithPermissions()
{

    #Connect to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.
    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
    $clientContext.Credentials = $credentials


    Function GetRole
    {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]$rType
        )

        $web = $clientContext.Web
        if ($web -ne $null)
        {
            $roleDefs = $web.RoleDefinitions
            $clientContext.Load($roleDefs)
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
            $roleDef = $roleDefs | Where-Object { $_.RoleTypeKind -eq $rType }
            return $roleDef
        }
        return $null
    }

    #Get the SharePoint web
    $web = $clientContext.Web;
    $clientContext.Load($web)

    #Get the groups
    $groups = $web.SiteGroups
    $clientContext.Load($groups)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()


    #Read CSV File and iterate
    $csv = Import-CSV $csvfilepath
    foreach ($row in $csv)
    {

        #Create Folder
        $folder = $web.Folders.Add($libname + '/' + $row.Folder)
        $clientContext.Load($folder)
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        #Assign Role
        $group = $groups.GetByName($row.Group)
        $clientContext.Load($group)
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        $roleType= $row.Role
        $roleTypeObject = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]$roleType
        $roleObj = GetRole $roleTypeObject
        $usrRDBC = $null
        $usrRDBC = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($clientContext)
        $usrRDBC.Add($roleObj)

         #Remove inherited permissions
        $folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)
        $clientContext.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($group, $usrRDBC))
        $folder.Update()
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        #Display the folder name and permission
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Folder Name: ' $folder.Name ' Group: '$row.Group ' Role: ' $roleType;

    }

}
#Execute the function
CreateFolderWithPermissions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what `split` method you tried, but executing `$row.Group.Split(",")` works fine on the two sample rows your provided, including the case where there is only one group in the field.  Don't forget that after you `.Split(",")`, you then have to loop through your split result. The following should work:

```
#Get the user credentials
$username = "username"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

#Input Parameters
$url = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/site1"
$csvfilepath ='C:\temp\data.csv'
$libname ='Shared Documents/Folder1'

#References
Add-Type -Path 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'


#CreateFolder with Permissions Function
function CreateFolderWithPermissions()
{

    #Connect to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.
    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
    $clientContext.Credentials = $credentials


    Function GetRole
    {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]$rType
        )

        $web = $clientContext.Web
        if ($web -ne $null)
        {
            $roleDefs = $web.RoleDefinitions
            $clientContext.Load($roleDefs)
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
            $roleDef = $roleDefs | Where-Object { $_.RoleTypeKind -eq $rType }
            return $roleDef
        }
        return $null
    }

    #Get the SharePoint web
    $web = $clientContext.Web;
    $clientContext.Load($web)

    #Get the groups
    $groups = $web.SiteGroups
    $clientContext.Load($groups)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()


    #Read CSV File and iterate
    $csv = Import-CSV $csvfilepath
    foreach ($row in $csv)
    {
        #split groups from csv
        $rowgroups = $row.group.split(",");

        foreach ($rowGroup in $rowgroups)
        {
            #Create Folder
            $folder = $web.Folders.Add($libname + '/' + $row.Folder)
            $clientContext.Load($folder)
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

            #Assign Role
            $group = $groups.GetByName($rowGroup)
            $clientContext.Load($group)
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

            $roleType= $row.Role
            $roleTypeObject = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]$roleType
            $roleObj = GetRole $roleTypeObject
            $usrRDBC = $null
            $usrRDBC = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($clientContext)
            $usrRDBC.Add($roleObj)

             #Remove inherited permissions
            $folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)
            $clientContext.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($group, $usrRDBC))
            $folder.Update()
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

            #Display the folder name and permission
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Folder Name: ' $folder.Name ' Group: '$rowGroup ' Role: ' $roleType;
        }
    }

}
#Execute the function
CreateFolderWithPermissions
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried something similar but I was missing ';' at the end of the split line and struggling to get my head around where to insert the 'foreach' So simple when you know how.